# g++ compilation of a separately preprocessed file gives error depending on the architecture

Tags: c++, architecture, compiler-errors, g++, standard-library

I am using g++ version 4.1.2 on a x64_86 GNU linux architecture. Code base is very huge and I don't have sufficient understanding of makefiles used in the project. The code compiles fine as it is.

For some debugging purpose, I need to preprocess (`g++ -E`) few source files individually and then re-compile it. I am giving the required include paths using `-I`. Ideally the compilation should go fine.

But I am getting few discrepancies in standard headers like:

1. `typedef unsigned long size_t;` causes errors with `operator new()`
   declaration generated by compiler (if I change to `unsigned int`
   manually then this error disappears)
2. In library functions like `unsigned long numeric_limits<>::max()`,
   compiler complains for big numbers such as `922...807L`; it generates
   compiler error as `integer constant is too large for long type`
3. Mismatch declaration of `__errorno_location()` gives compiler error

I am having hard time finding what is going wrong. Why compilation goes fine when I do make on unchanged file and why standard headers start cribbing when I give `g++ -I <> -E` option on individual file ?

(Note that there is no problem with the code we have written, it's just from standard library side. I tried locating the `stddef.h` which has `unsigned int` as typedef, but that just fixes the 1st problem. )

Any idea to fix this errors would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see/find the exact compiler command line used to build the object files? The include paths aren't that important (pre-processing would just fail), other options could be. (Just a guess.)

Comment: Maybe you can post a small example file (it seems like all you should need is something that uses `size_t` with `new` - but I'm not really sure) along with the exact command line(s) involved.  I sure don't have a clear idea of exactly what you're doing.

Comment: And what does "standard headers start cribbing" mean?

Comment: @Mat, in this case include paths are making the difference; Suppose, i am processing a file like `A/B/C/x.cpp` then I need to find all the dependencies which are `#include` in `x.cpp`. Anyways, I am using `g++ -E` for individual preprocessing of the file. For general purpose, we have to use `make`; What command should I post ? (we do some `source` from a `bash` file, before `make`)

Comment: @MichaelBurr, by `standard header cribbing`, i meant the problem is occuring at standard definitions like `operator new (size_t)` and whatever I have mentioned in the code examples. There is no problem with our code. So, it seems that while preprocessing a file, I might be including wrong directory. What part exactly you want me to post, because the example file itself will be very large.

Comment: You need to reproduce the exact same compiler invocation as is run when you build your source (plus the `-E` obviously). Can't you have that?

Comment: @Mat, that's where I am very weak. I have never learned makefile, this command should be hiding somewhere in makefile and I don't know how to find it. I tried various greps and finds, but no luck. You have any rough idea, what text I should find in various makefiles ? (e.g. `CPP_FLAGS`, `g++`)

Comment: Don't you see the commands output when you build your source? (If you really can't figure out how to get that, there's a really crappy way of getting it (replace g++ with a wrapper that logs all invocations before invoking the real g++), but that's really last resort.)

Comment: Try to see if you have lines that start with `<tab>@$(CXX) ...`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11392/discussion-between-iammilind-and-mat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't preprocess and compile separately, or if you must then use consistent compiler options and a consistent environment.

It sounds a though you're running the preprocessor on a 32-bit machine (or using the `-m32` option) then compiling on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Preprocessing differently is needed in my case for some debugging. Accepting your answer for `-m32` which is the root cause of 1 and 2 errors from my question.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling the output of the preprocessor, make sure that you use the`-fpreprocessed` compiler option so that the preprocessor will not run again.

If you don't pass in that option certain constructs that produced identifiers that look like macros may get expanded again into something they shouldn't get expanded to.  It's hard for me to come up with a case that shows a difference (I'm sure I can, but it would take a bit of puzzling out and would be pretty contrived). However, the implementation headers may well use some arcane macro techniques that might be sensitive to this option.